# Safari not loading my styles.min.css

Tags: html, css, safari

So after making a website using VScode (Probably not important) and uploading it to GitHub Pages, the website looked great! It was doing fine on windows and on my phone, everything was looking good.

Then, after checking it on my Mac with Safari (Not sure which would be the issue but I presume Safari) the css seemed to be a little weird and the page layout was all over the place.

After checking the console I am getting the following error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

This is my styles.min.css file so I presume this is the issue.

Checking the console on windows doesn't bring around any errors which leads me to believe that this is the error...

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

I'll post some pictures of what is happening to the items within my website.

[image: coding issue]

Since people want the code, hopefully posting the website so you can inspect it will be fine? There's a lot of code and I'm not sure where to upload it.

https://manakura.github.io

EDIT 1: After checking out the code in the console, it seems like it has something to do with the width of the text? Because if I change the class from >col-md-4 to >col-md-3 which has less width the page is fixed.

Though I'm not sure how to fix this with col-md-4 or if I will have to enter some kind of media query?

Website working in Chrome on MacOS

[image: coding issue]

Comment: Welcome to So, Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: @EvinceDevelopment Hi, thanks for the reply! I've added the link to the GitHub page so that you can inspect and see the code for yourself! Thank you.

Comment: Please try in the link element add the attribute and value :

`type="text/css"`

Comment: There's no file called `styles.min.css`

Comment: Try to open the direct URL of `styles.min.css` and hard refresh it `Opt + Cmd + E`, it could be a cache issue.

Comment: @ExillustX I thought the same thing, however hard refreshing it doesn't fix the issue either..

Comment: Well the best thing you can do now is to check it on other browsers with hard refreshing, looking at what JBdouble05 said, your file doesn't exist so maybe the other browsers are using the cache copy of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there is no file actually named `styles.min.css` in the Github repo. You need to create a file first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is this something that would only be a problem with safari? Because if that's the case, then there's no styles.min.css on windows either but the page layout is fine...?

Comment: I'm using Safari right now, will check on Chrome. But the point is, there's no `styles.min.css` file

Comment: Ahh, I see. No, I'm not sure why that is - try editing your files with `-webkit-`

Comment: It's pretty weird, although I have just figured out that if I make the width of the text a little smaller then it falls back into place making me feel like it's overflowing in safari for some strange reason.

Comment: Wow. That sounds like a bug. Look at Ask Different maybe.

Comment: checked with firefox in MacOs. the file does not exist either.

Comment: checked with Chrome in MacOs. the file returns also 404. I don't see it working in any browser.

Comment: @Dknacht It works fine in Chrome with MacOs on my computer. This is completely something to do with Safari it seems. (Although running it through safari's developer 'chrome' doesn't work)

Comment: As I said, I tested it on chrome and Firefox, and it didn't work. I think the file is not there and your chrome has it cached. Test it on chrome with the incognito window and see if it still works please.

Comment: As I said, It works on Chrome with MacOS. I did hard refresh, added a screenshot of the website working on Chrome with MacOS in incognito.

Comment: @Dknacht Seems the issue is to do with the 'row' class. As soon as I remove that class everything works fine with Safari. I'll dig a little deeper.

Comment: @OliverRiley See if resetting Safari helps.

Comment: I see. Maybe it clashed with a reserved word. But it that would be the case then the error wouldn't be 404. I don't know.

Comment: You don't have a file on your repo called `styles.min.css` anywhere. You do however have one called `styles.css`. Was this a typo?